# How to get all the form elements values using name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to access the form elements in a jsp page using the name attribute. this form contains text,textarea and select fields. now in my javascript file i have to get these values.

```
$("input[name=first_name]").val()
```

By using this we can get only values of input type fields (for ex:text) and not  and  fields.

Please help me to resolve this.i want to use jquery code for this.

Comment: I am trying to get the all fields values at a time as an array.but the above code will give me only input type field values not <textarea> and <select> values in a form. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the type of element in the selector:

```
$("[name=other_name]").val()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector:

```
$(':input[name="first_name"]').val()
```

Also note that having multiple form elements (text fields, textareas, select boxes) with the same name is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var form = $("#form_id");
//form['name_of_input_field']
```

this is much quicker than using selectors.

Comment: Wouldn't this look for a dom element of type 'form_id' in the same way that $('div') would look for divs?

Comment: `$('divs')` will return object that has id ="divs"

Comment: Umm, no, not really, to select by ID you need to use $('#id_of_element') - take note of the hash(#).  The selectors are based on CSS syntax.

Comment: Yes i forgot about that, im not using jQuery, preffer mootools.